# OpenJDK in docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, java

Currently I have the following in my docker-compose:

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    depends_on:
      - 'postgres'
      - 'elasticsearch'
      - 'java'
    build: .
    command: bash scripts/start.sh
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/farma_alg_reborn'
    volumes_from:
    - box
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: elasticsearch:9200

  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:9.5'
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'

  elasticsearch:
    image: 'elasticsearch:2'
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
    volumes:
      - 'elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data'
    environment:
      - Des.network.host=0.0.0.0

  box:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - /box

  java:
    image: openjdk:latest


volumes:
  postgres:
  box:
  elasticsearch:
```

In my rails application started up with this compose file, I would like to  call embed bash commands `java` and `javac`, but they're not found (sh: 1: javac: not found) when I try it.

How can I make that work?

EDIT 1:

My dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.4-slim

RUN apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends \
  build-essential nodejs npm libpq-dev git fp-compiler nodejs-legacy libfontconfig1-dev cron
RUN npm install -g phantomjs

ENV APP /farma_alg_reborn

RUN mkdir -p $APP

WORKDIR $APP

ENV BUNDLE_PATH /box

COPY . $APP
```

Comment: Can you provide the dockerfile for app?

Comment: What is the reason you want to do that? There might be a better way to do it

Comment: Question updated with my dockerfile @yamenK

Comment: @TarunLalwani my app have the role to act like an interface to run simple java source codes. In other words, the user will enter a source code to answer a question, and the app compile and run it to check if is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install java-jdk inside your ruby app image in order to be able to run java commands.